# auval: Cocoa Views Available: 0

Tags: core-audio, audiounit

auval is reporting:

Cocoa Views Available: 0

**How can I troubleshoot this?** I've started with the XCode AUv3 template, and then added my own AudioUnit, which I already use in my stand-alone app. Validation passes otherwise, but I can't load the UI in Logic.

**Update**

The AUv3 example code here no longer builds: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioUnitV3Example/Introduction/Intro.html

I got it building, but then I get the same error (Cocoa Views Available: 0), and it doesn't load in Logic either:

[image: AUV3FilterDemo not loading in logic]

Same issue in GarageBand:

[image: AUV3FilterDemo not loading in GarageBand]

I've filed a Developer Tech Support Incident, so hopefully they'll help me out.

Comment: did filing a Tech Support Ticket help? I am running into all kind of weird issues with this.